# Approved tag wiki edits do not appear on Android mobile app

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, android-app, tag-wiki, achievements-dialog

I noticed that after a couple of tag wiki edits that I suggested were accepted my reputation on that site had gone up but on the Android mobile app I didn't see anything on the achievements page.

After checking in a browser and seeing the changes there I assumed there maybe just a delay or something but now it has been a couple of days and they have still not appeared the app.

I assume this is a bug and that these approvals should be listed on the achievements page.